# AFNetworking 2.0.0-RC2: No visible @interface for 'DNHackerNewsAPIClient' declares the selector 'getPath:parameters:success:failure:'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, ios7, afnetworking-2

I'm Using AFNetworking 2.0.0-RC2 added to my project via Cocoapods. Trying to use my first method, to make a call to a webservice, looking at the example project from the AFNetworking it looks fine. But for some reason with my project, I can't get it to work.

DNAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DNAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

+ (void)globalTimelinePostsWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))block;

@end
```

DNAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "DNAppDelegate.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.h"
#import "DNHackerNewsAPIClient.h"

@class DNHackerNewsAPIClient;

@implementation DNAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //AFNetworking setup
    NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024 diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];

    //Call API


    //Window work
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

+ (void)globalTimelinePostsWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))block {
// ^ ERROR HAPPENS ON THIS METHOD
    [[DNHackerNewsAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"page" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
        NSArray *postsFromResponse = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data"];



//        if (block) {
//            block([NSArray arrayWithArray:mutablePosts], nil);
//        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (block) {
            block([NSArray array], error);
        }
    }];
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or     SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its     current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the     user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Edit:

DNHackerNewsAPIClient.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@interface DNHackerNewsAPIClient : AFHTTPClient

+ (DNHackerNewsAPIClient *)sharedClient;

@end
```

DNHackerNewsAPIClient.m:

```
#import "DNHackerNewsAPIClient.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

static NSString * const kDNHackerNewsAPIBaseURLString = @"http://api.ihackernews.com/";

@implementation DNHackerNewsAPIClient

//Setup the singleton to use throught the life of the application
+ (DNHackerNewsAPIClient *)sharedClient {
    static DNHackerNewsAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[DNHackerNewsAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kDNHackerNewsAPIBaseURLString]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

//    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
//    
//    // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
//  [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

    return self;
}

@end
```

What am I missing?

EDIT 2:

Why does this never seem to fire?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.ihackernews.com/"];
DNHackerNewsAPIClient *HNClient = [[DNHackerNewsAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

[HNClient
    GET:@"page"
    parameters:nil
    success:^(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject)
 {
        NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", response);
     NSLog(@"Y U NO WORK.");
 }
    failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"It Failed: %@", error);
 }];
```

Comment: It appears as though the `DNHackerNewsAPIClient` class doesn't have the method the compiler complains about. What is the code of the `DNHackerNewsAPIClient` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because some method signatures have changed on 2.0. You should use now the following one:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
               parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                  success:(void (^)(NSHTTPURLResponse *, id))success
                  failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure
```

I strongly recommend that you put your `globalTimelinePostsWithBlock:` inside your `APIClient` and don't use `AFNetworking` methods anywhere else. This way, you can encapsulate `AFNetworking`, making it easy to fix whenever a method changes.

Comment: Yes, no more errors there! Thank you.  I updated my question, now I can't seem to get the HTTP GET block to ever fire. Hmmmm...

Answer (score 0):

In your appDelegate your are using a forward declaration. (@class DNHackerNewsAPIClient). You should import it.

```
#import "DNHackerNewsAPIClient.h"
```